# How to trigger XL Release task from Jenkins ? Is it possible?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, xlrelease

I have a CI pipeline configured on Jenkins. When the jobs execute successfully, I want a trigger to pass on to XL Release so that it automatically triggers the deployment process. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the Jenkins-XLR plugin that you can install straight from Jenkins. In Jenkins, go to **Manage Jenkins** > **Manage Plugins** and search for the XL Release plugin.

The plugin page is here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XL+Release+Plugin

Some more information can be found in this [blog post](http://blog.xebialabs.com/2014/05/18/three-ways-using-xl-release-jenkins-continuous-delivery-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

One other approach you could consider is having XL Release drive your CI, by creating a Build / (Provision) / Deploy / Test template.   This template polls your SCM, and when kicked off, executes the phases:

- **Build Phase:**  Jenkins plugin to run Jenkins, and store output to variable
- **Provision Phase:** Some customers have this phase, since they need to run Salt/Puppet/Chef/Ansible type provisioning as part of the overall deployment
- **Deploy Phase:** XL Deploy plugin
- **Test Phase:** Kick off any other tests you do as part of the deployment

Some  benefits to this approach:

- XL Release gives you visibility / information across the disparate tools used for delivery
- If you include testing in each phase, you can make decisions about proceeding or not during each phase
- You could automatically kick off subsequent releases (to QA, for example) if the entire release passed.

You can also see an example this here [XLRelease Provision, Build, Deploy and Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80Jc6kx7yv8/)